# DaisyChain Non-Apple monitors to Macbook Pro

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook-pro, displayport, thunderbolt

I as hoping to daisychain some monitors to either my display port or my thunderbolt port for my early 2011 Macbook Pro (AMD Radeon HD 6490M).  I don't want to buy the expensive Apple monitors but I'm not sure what specs I need to check to ensure that I can daisy chain the monitors.   For example would this work? 
[http://www.amazon.com/Dell-P2210-Wide-LCD-Monitor/dp/B00347A48O](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00347A48O)

Comment: Did you try it? I want a dual monitor on my MacBook as a christmas gift.